# Quantum Mechanics - Rectangular Potential Barrier - Normalisation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, scattering, hilbert-space, normalization

I have a quick question regarding the normalisation of the wave function of a particle incident on a potential barrier specifically regarding the normalisation of the wave functions.

The problem is set up as on this webpage:

https://www.ntmdt.com/spm-basics/view/tunneling-effect

And through consideration of the boundary conditions (continuity of wave function and derivative of wave function) the final wave function looks like this:

[image: Diagram 1]

My question is: are the wave functions either side of the barrier normalisable? And if not does this mean the situation is not physical?

Answer (score 1):

They are not normalisable because they either come from, or extend to infinity. This essentially means that the probability density blows off and gives non-physical results.

Comment: It's worth adding that if you enclose the wave in some envelope that falls off at infinity and becomes normalizable without changing the picture here too much.